# AttributeError: 'SVC' object has no attribute 'best_estimator_'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, gridsearchcv

I'm trying to use GridSearchCV for SVM linear but I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'SVC' object has no attribute 'best_estimator_'
```

the code of the SVM linear:

```
classifier = SVC()
classifier = GridSearchCV(classifier, {'C':[0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10,0.1, 100, 1000]}, cv=3, n_jobs=4)
classifier = SVC(kernel='linear')
classifier.fit(train_vectors, train_labels)
classifier = classifier.best_estimator_
```

can anyone help?

Comment: you replaced `classifier` from GridSearch returned estimator to `SVC` on line 3rd. How are you expecting SVC object to have `best_estimator` parameter?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't notice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
classifier = SVC(kernel='linear')
gridsearch = GridSearchCV(classifier, {'C':[0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10,0.1, 100, 1000]}, cv=3, n_jobs=4)
gridsearch.fit(train_vectors, train_labels)

best_params = gridsearch.best_params_
classifier = gridsearch.best_estimator_
```